# Differential Equation: Existence and Uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a bit of a confusion with this problem involving the existence/uniqueness of a differential equation, the problem goes,

Determine if the differential equation has a solution and if it is unique using the existence and uniqueness theorems

$y' = \frac{10}{3}xy^{\frac{2}{5}}$, $y(x_o)=y_o$

So this is my attempt on answering this problem

First we know that $f(x,y) = \frac{10}{3}xy^{\frac{2}{5}}$ and it is continuous near $x_o=y_o$,

then by existence theorem, **A solution exist**.

Next, we get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ of $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{10}{3}xy^{\frac{2}{5}}$

we have,

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&= \left(\frac{10}{3}x\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y^{\frac{2}{5}}\\
&=\left(\frac{10}{3}x\right)\left(\frac{2}{5}y^{\frac{-3}{5}}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{20x}{15y^{\frac{3}{5}}}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{4x}{3y^{\frac{3}{5}}}\right)\\
\end{align}

From this, is it okay to conclude that the differential equation has a unique solution when $y(x_o)\neq0$?

Comment: Can you explicit the argument for unicity? it is not clear in your question. You should mention precisely the theorem you want to use.

Comment: The solution exist, and it is unique if $f(x,y)and \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are both continuous near $x_o=y_o$

Comment: Now it remains to show whether in the remaining case $y_0=0$ you actually get different solutions to the same IVP.